# How is `let` implemented in Clojure and what is its overhead?

Tags: performance, clojure, let

I can see 2 ways of implementing `let` bindings. First, as known from [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_thm_4.6), `let` may be implemented as **lambda function**. This is convenient and simple, but taking into account the fact that each lambda (`fn`) is translated into separate class in JVM and the number of times `let` is used in average program, this seems very, very expensive.

Second, `let` bindings may be translated directly into **local Java variables**. This gives very little overhead, but storing bindings on a stack breaks language semantics: in this case creation of closures is just impossible - saved values will be destroyed just after stack unwinding.

So what is actual implementation used in Clojure? Pointing to corresponding lines in Clojure source is appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`let`-bound variables are stored as **final** local values on the stack.

Since they are final, they can be bound into closures if needed (this is analogous how you can use a final local variable in an anonymous inner class in Java). Under the hood, the JVM copies the value into the object that represents the closure (where it is stored as a final field). As a result, the closure still works even after the stack frame goes away.

Overall, let-bound variables are extremely low overhead, you should have no hesitation at all from using them from a performance perspective. It probably isn't possible to do any better on the JVM.

Comment: So I understand closure object is created (and final variables are copied to it) only when needed and for simple cases vars stay on the stack only?

Comment: yes, that's pretty much how it works. If you are interested you can have a dig around in: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java (though it's not particularly easy to figure out what Clojure's compiler is doing, there is a lot of "magic")

Comment: @ffriend Java has block scoped variables (as opposed to method scope). I haven't looked at what the Clojure compiler does but it seems that *let* can simply be implemented by a block of code containing final variables. I'm not sure why you think it would have be implemented with a closure.

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin: Aren't block scoped variables stored on stack? In this case the problem remains: after stack unwinding these vars will be unavailable. So to get their values later they are to be copied somewhere in memory, e.g. in closure object (closures are just the way some Lisp implementations do this, in Java it may be any other kind of objects). I guessed that additional objects for storing these vars are created only when needed, but wasn't sure. mikera's answer made this more clear.

Comment: @ffriend Anonymous inner classes in Java close over final variables and final method arguments. I guess my point is that a lambda (anonymous class) instance will maintains a copy of the closed over variables. And *let* specifically should not consist of anything but scoped final variables initialization. Then again I haven't looked at what the compiler is actually doing...

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are pointers, allocated on the stack, pointing to values/objects on the heap. The pointer goes out of scope, but the object remains alive as long as the closure retains a pointer to it.